# Deleting fields in SQLite3 (dbBrowser) where id matches a certain input

Tags: python, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am trying to delete a row where the email address corresponds to the user input. However, it always throws back an error.

```
column_2 = 'Email'
table_name = 'Personal_Information'
cn = 'Email'
deleting_user = easygui.multenterbox(msg1, title, fieldNames)
deleting_email = deleting_user[2]
dbCursor.execute("DELETE ({coi}) FROM {tn} WHERE {cn}='{user}'".\
     format(coi=column_2, tn=table_name, cn=column_2, user = deleting_email))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's your error?

Comment: You should read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html btw.

Comment: The error is a syntax error (however the same method works for updating information, so im not sure why I get a syntax error for deleting fields) 


sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Thanks @shawn, the link you provided showed me the proper structure. Fixed the issue now.